# cmake cross compile windows binary from WSL2 using clang/llvm

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, clang, cross-compiling

I'm tring to compile windows binary from `WSL2` using `clang` and `llvm` using this cmake file:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(MyProject
  VERSION 0.1.0
  DESCRIPTION ""
  HOMEPAGE_URL ""
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

set(TARGET_NAME testapp)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})

target_compile_features(${TARGET_NAME}
  PRIVATE cxx_std_20)

set(RELEASE_OPTIONS
  -Wall
  -Wextra
  -flto
)

set(DEBUG_OPTIONS
  -Wall
  -Wextra
  -fno-omit-frame-pointer
  -fno-sanitize-recover=all
  -fsanitize=address,undefined
)

target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME}
  PRIVATE
  $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${RELEASE_OPTIONS}>
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_OPTIONS}>)

target_link_options(${TARGET_NAME}
  PRIVATE
  $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${RELEASE_OPTIONS}>
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_OPTIONS}>)
```

`cmake/toolchians_windows.cmake`

```
# set target operating to windows
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# set compiler to clang
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER /usr/bin/llvm-rc)

# where is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
  # libraries
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/ucrt/x64"
  # includes
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/include"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/ucrt"
)

# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

```bash
cmake -S . -B build_windows -G 'Ninja Multi-Config' -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='cmake/toolchains_windows.cmake'
```

However this configuraion fails to find libraries

```
...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:63 (message):
...
    lld-link: error: could not open 'kernel32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'user32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'gdi32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'winspool.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'shell32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'ole32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'oleaut32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'uuid.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'comdlg32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'advapi32.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'oldnames.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'msvcrtd.lib': No such file or directory
...
```

I thought providing these paths to `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` handles finding libs/headers but it didn't.

So I added this code to the `cmake/toolchains_windows.cmake`

```
include_directories(
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/include"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/ucrt")
link_directories(
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/ucrt/x64")
```

Now it can compile `hello world` program!

```bash
cmake -S . -B build_windows -G 'Ninja Multi-Config' -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='cmake/toolchains_windows.cmake'

cmake --build build_windows -v --config Release

# it works!
```

However when I try to use `-fsanitize=address,undefined` it fails.

```
...
FAILED: Debug/testapp.exe 
: && /usr/bin/clang++ --target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc -fuse-ld=lld-link -nostartfiles -nostdlib -O0 -D_DEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrtd -g -Xclang -gcodeview -Xlinker /su
bsystem:console  -Wall -Wextra -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-sanitize-recover=all -fsanitize=address,undefined CMakeFiles/testapp.dir/Debug/src/main.cpp.obj -o Debug/testapp.exe -Xlin
ker /MANIFEST:EMBED -Xlinker /implib:Debug/testapp.lib -Xlinker /pdb:Debug/testapp.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0  -L"/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/
MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/x64"   -L"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64"   -L"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/ucrt/x64" -lkernel32 -lu
ser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames  && :
lld-link: error: could not open '/usr/lib64/clang/15.0.7/lib/windows/clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib': No such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open '/usr/lib64/clang/15.0.7/lib/windows/clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib': No such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open '/usr/lib64/clang/15.0.7/lib/windows/clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib': No such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open '/usr/lib64/clang/15.0.7/lib/windows/clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib': No such file or directory
clang-15.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

`clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib` is present in `/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/x64` so I don't know why this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to link with sanitizers but it's not perfect.

If anyone can improve this please do!

`cmake/toolchians_windows.cmake`

```
# set target operating to windows
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# set compiler to clang
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER /usr/bin/llvm-rc)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
  # libraries
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/lib/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/ucrt/x64"
  # includes
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/include"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/shared"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/ucrt"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/um"
)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# NOTE: workaround
# I don't know why `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` is not working
include_directories(
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/include"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/shared"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/ucrt"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22000.0/um")
link_directories(
  "/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/lib/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64"
  "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/ucrt/x64")

# NOTE: how to build with sanitizer
# - Currently leak sanitizer is not implemented for windows.
# - You need to download windows llvm and copy `<llvm-path>\lib\clang\15.0.7\lib\windows`
#   to `/usr/lib64/clang/<clang-version>/lib/windows`

# NOTE: workaround
# lld-link: error: /failifmismatch: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary':
# >>> clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib(ubsan_type_hash_win.cpp.obj) has value MT_StaticRelease
# >>> CMakeFiles/myproject.dir/Debug/src/main.cpp.obj has value MDd_DynamicDebug
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY MultiThreaded)

add_definitions(
  # NOTE: workaround
  # lld-link: error: /INFERASANLIBS is not allowed in .drectve
  # https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56300
  # -D_DISABLE_STRING_ANNOTATION
  -D_DISABLE_VECTOR_ANNOTATION)
```